# Finding a query from the DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I am looking through journeys I didn't build, and I am trying to understand who we are sending the emails to. I can see that we are using entry event with a DE. When I go to that DE, I can't tell what tables we are pulling from and all the fields are renamed. Is there a way for me to trace back where the actual query for that DE is saved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API to find the query via the name of your target DE.

Sample SOAP call:

```
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>QueryDefinition</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.Name</Properties>
        <Properties>DataExtensionTarget.CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
        <Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
           <q1:Property>DataExtensionTarget.Name</q1:Property>
           <q1:SimpleOperator>equals</q1:SimpleOperator>
           <q1:Value>{{yourTargetDEName}}</q1:Value>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

This will return a response that contains the name and customerkey of the Query that targets this DE. But, keep in mind, if multiple queries target this DE, the above Retrieve will return all of them.

Answer (score -1):

If that DE is being used as a target DE for a query you can go to automation studio > activities > sql query. And in the overview screen you can see the queries and the target DE

Comment: Is there any other way to find it? We have a lot of folders within folders in the SQL query section. I have clicked through most of them, and I can't seem to find the DE.

Comment: The Target Data Extension is not part of the search functionality in the activites tab. But tbh if you click on "All SQL Query" with the name of the target data extension in the browser search, it should not take long to find the query.

Comment: it could be populated through an import and not a query also